# How to handle fonts when generating pdf in laravel 5 with dompdf

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, laravel-5, dompdf

I started using [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/readme.md) today. I was able to run the demo loads html well but in the course of running the one that loads the file:

`return PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/myfile.html')->save('/path-to/my_stored_file.pdf')->stream('download.pdf');`

I got the following error message
`[2015-05-16 11:32:49] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(D:\xampp\htdocs\laraApps\...\storage/fonts/eb3e0c0cc4b263877903c9509310e3b3.ttf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in D:\xampp\htdocs\laraApps\...\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\include\font_metrics.cls.php:343
Stack trace:`

I even copied all my html dom in the file and pased in the 'loadHTML()' example, yet got the same error message.

This how the header of my html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Birth certificate template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style type="text/css">
#header{ text-align: center;}
.ans{ border-bottom: dotted 2px #999; padding: 2px 0 1px 2px; margin:0       !important; width:90%; }
.ans-head{ border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px 0 1px 0;}
#frame{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}

li{ display:block;} 
div { display:block;}
</style>
</head>
```

I really need help. Thanks

Comment: I solved this problem by making the path to my css file absolute.

Comment: stickling point: you're claiming to be using HTML5 with that `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but the HTML you're actually using follows HTML4.01 conventions instead. In HTML5, it's just `<meta charset="utf-8">` (there is also no 'self-closing' `/>`tag closing in HTML5). Similarly it's just `<link ... >`, and <style> <script> elements are by default for CSS and JS, *unless* you specify a type attribute to override that. If you use them for their normal purpose, you don't add the type attribute (not even 'just to be clear'. You already forced the browser to explicitly parse as HTML5 with the doctype)

Comment: Mike thank you very much for drawing my attention to versions of html. Thank you.